# Designing activity with two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

How do i proceed with designing an android activity with two fragments such their layout are as follows in landscape and portrait mode respectively. I tried putting two fragments inside a frame layout set as vertical but it didnt work. I tried this with linear layout but didnt get expected result

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    class="com.examples.fragments.Fragment1" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    class="com.examples.fragments.Fragment2" /></LinearLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Create an Activity with 2 Fragments. You can do this in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

A `FrameLayout` doesn't have an orientation. You should use a `LinearLayout`. It supports the `android:orientation` attribute.

And by the looks of your disign you might need to use [`android:layout_weight`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) with `android:layout_height="0dp"` (or `android:layout_width="0dp"`) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a LinearLayout with orientation attribute. You can design two different layout. Check this link for this second approach:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html